# Insert into local sql lite databse recived Push Notification from Firebase Cloud messeging

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to write to local sql lite database in `onMessageReceived` method in `class Notification` witch `extends FirebaseMessagingService`. But no luck with this.The notification is recieved to the phone its get the data I handle the data parameter in M`ain Activity`. But the actual insert statment is not inserting into the database.Any help will be helpful.Thank you

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    
          // Insert into databse here

    }
```

Comment: What the code that writes data into the database and doesn't work the way you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I) onMessageReceived method works only on foreground so you can't catch all message from firebase using this method.***

***II) If you want catch background notification you can do like this, but this method works when user click to notification:***

**1. On MainActivity.java file this file must be first launcher file, add this code:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            //bundle must contain all info sent in "data" field of the notification
            if (bundle.get("data") != null) {
                Utils.saveToLocalDB(data,context);
            }
        }
   }
```

**2. In FirebaseNotificationService.java file add this code:**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String notifText = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() + " / " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()
        Utils.saveToLocalDB(notifText, context);
    }


}
```

**3) Install this dependencies, add this to app's build.gradle**

```
def room_version = "2.4.3"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

[If you need more information about room database click here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

**4) Create NotifModel.java class file and add this code in that file:**

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class NotifModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    private String message;

    public NotifModel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    }
```

**5) Create NotifDao.java interface file and add this code into that file:**

```
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import java.util.List;
@Dao
public interface NotifDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifmodel")
    List<NotifDao> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(NotifModel notifModel);

    @Delete
    void delete(NotifModel notifModel);
}
```

**6) Create NotifDatabase.java abstract class and add this code into that file:**

```
import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;

@Database(entities = {NotifModel.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class NotifDatabase  extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract NotifDao notifDao();
}
```

**7) Create Utils.java class and add this code into that file:**

```
public class Utils {
    public static void saveToLocalDB(String message,Context context){
        NotifDatabase db= Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                NotifDatabase.class, "notif_db").allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
        NotifDao notifDao=db.notifDao();
        notifDao.insertAll(new NotifModel(message));
    }
}
```

**8) When you send notification from firebase dashboard or backend you must add additional data called with "data". This "data" include notification title and body in one string variable.**

**9) Sqlite is deprecated so I use Room database**

Comment: I write wrong code here: @Query("SELECT * FROM notifmodel")
    List<NotifDao> getAll();

Comment: This is true code : @Query("SELECT * FROM notifmodel")
    List<NotifModel > getAll();

Comment: OK anyway i implemeted it old fashion way with sqllite  but the answer is good